# Movie, Image Editing, Mixing Audio in IPhone

Tags: iphone, editing, movie

I need to develop some sort of application featuring Editing Movie slices, Adding and editing images, Adding sound  . recording movie, Adding effects, setting transitions between  movie clips and images.

so is there any provision in SDK 3.0? I will use iPhone 3GS

Please Help Me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a lot of support for a program like this on the iPhone yet.  With the 3GS and OS 3.0, your program can let the user record a video and trim it, but everything after that is left to you to do from scratch.  You get the filename of the recorded video, but there are no OS calls to even do something as simple as find out how many seconds of video there are.